# Make current OpenGL context on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, opengl

On Windows I do

```
HGLRC glContext       = wglGetCurrentContext();
HDC   deviceGLContext = wglGetCurrentDC();
wglMakeCurrent(glContext, deviceGLContext);
```

On Linux there are analogous functions for getting current GL context and current device context, `glXGetCurrentContext` and `glXGetCurrentDisplay`, respectively. But I am stuck with

```
Bool glXMakeCurrent( Display *dpy,
  GLXDrawable drawable,
  GLXContext ctx )
```

I don't know how to deal with the second parameter. I use **Qt** for GUI, but I still need several Windows API function, among which are the three ones mentioned above.

How to make the invoke `glXMakeCurrent` in the same fashion described at the beginning of the post? The problem is that I don't know how to get `GLXDrawable`.

I need to get a GLXContext, then create another one to share Display lists, and make it current in another thread, add it to OpenCL context attributes. The point is that I need to be able to make it current.

Comment: I've tried to answer you, but not really sure what your problem is. If you can clarify exactly what the problem is, I might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Qt has a nice abstraction for GL contexts and drawing, why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

That 'GLXDrawable' is the X11 window for which you have got the context.

If you are using qt, I would have assumed it would have provided a 'myWindow.makeCurrent()' function, or something to the effect.

You can make a window using `XCreateWindow` (there is also a function for making a basic window with less options). Before this, you will need to have got a connection to the display using `XOpenDisplay`.

I have been very short on the details here, as there is a lot steps for getting an OpenGL Context in an X11 window, and whilst not hard, does involve a lot of error checking. I suggest you make use of a library that handles this for you.

Comment: I would like to remind you that I am using Qt and don't need to create a window. I need to get a get GLXContext, then create another one to share Display lists, and make it current. The point is that I need to be able to make it current.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can add right now. I told you that the X11 function to make the context 'current' requires a window, suggested that you use a library that takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Windows, in X11 you are dealing with a client server model. The "display" represents the connection to the X11 server. In X11 there are Drawables, which can be used interchangably. One kind of Drawable are Windows.

You might want to have a look at
https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl
for an example on how to create OpenGL window with a transparent background using plain X11/GLX, that can be used in compositing.

--

#### Update

> I need to get a GLXContext, then create another one to share Display lists, and make it current in another thread, add it to OpenCL context attributes. The point is that I need to be able to make it current.

Familiar problem. My solution to this is to treat a QGLWidget as if it was a context. In your other thread create another QGLWidget, that will never be shown and pass the visible QGLWidget instance into the sharing parameter of the constructor. Then you can use the QGLWidget as if it were a context. It's dirty, not really to the point, but Qt's internal OpenGL system is that way.

Comment: @user14416 I dug around his repo, I think [this](https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/6ae3ddce77ff91c9b66f4f0c993ab85885dd5d14/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c) is what he wanted you to see. Perhaps a little bit more then you would need to know, but it should cover what you need. I still strongly suggest you make use of an existing library rather then try to write X code yourself.

Comment: @user14416: What's wrong with using a QGLWidget? You can perfectly well setup context data sharing between QGLWidgets. What however doesn't work is migrating a single context between QGLWidgets. I tried to patch that into Qt, but I was offended by the coding style of the lower level parts responsible for creating QGLWidgets.