# How to implement two same OpenGL UserControl in the same one form with C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, visual-c++-6

I tried to implement(i.e. draw on) two UserControl with the same OpenGL context in the same one form. In other words, i wanna show two same picture simultaneous on the form. My tool is VC6 and use C++.

I've tried many methods but failed. Could someone give me a simple sample code or some advises?

Comment: What is a "UserControl"?

Comment: VC6 is awfully old, get Qt 5 + mingw, and your form and UserControl will come to life.

Comment: The way I understand your question, you wish to display two images within an opengl canvas, and implement button like behaviour on top of these images. Is that correct?

Comment: @NicolBolas It's a 3D object.

Answer (score -2):

**edit**

It looks like there's two possibilities - either copy the final image to the second GUI element or create a second "device context" for the second element, use *MakeCurrent to change to it (see link and discussion below) and re-render or blit the result.

Copy:
Assuming the GL context draws directly to your primary GUI element (which would stop you using the GUI library to do the copy), you can copy the data via [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) or investigate drawing to a texture via a Frame Buffer Object and use [glGetTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml). Then I guess find some way to display the raw image data on the second GUI element (this part I have no experience in).

MakeCurrent:
[Make current OpenGL context on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777359/make-current-opengl-context-on-linux)

Comment: This is not correct: `OpenGL only supports a single main framebuffer`. OpenGL does in fact define no main framebuffers at all; it does declare that when being bound to a drawable that there is some kind of visible framebuffer, but that one is not specific to the context. A OpenGL context may be bound to any drawable that's compatible with it, each drawable being a own, independent framebuffer.

Comment: @datenwolf OK, let me rephrase. When ever I've used OpenGL (webgl, android, java, python, c/c++), there's always a default buffer I can draw to (regardless of the specs). With the exception of webgl, I can explicitly request double buffering. I can also bind an FBO to change my render target/s instead of what ever we're calling this default (or "main") target. What I haven't ever seen is multiple default/"main" targets, which I have taken the OP to be asking about. Can you help... do you know if this is possible?

Comment: WebGL is not OpenGL. And the Android/Java bindings for OpenGL wrap it up in constraints. But if you use OpenGL on the system level, i.e. create the context using WGL, GLX or EGL, you have a particular function called `{wgl,glX,egl}MakeCurrent` which takes as parameters the context **and** the drawable it should be made active on. As long as the context is compatible to the drawable you can switch the context arbitrarily between drawables, which may even reside in different top level windows, or be off-screen altogether. Your answer as you've given it is just plain wrong.

Comment: That default framebuffer you're *assuming* is just the window the OpenGL context gets bound to by the convenience wrappers. But in fact when a OpenGL context is first created, there's a `*MakeCurrent` call being made.

Comment: Thank you. I've never used multiple threads, contexts or even windows with OpenGL before. This sounds similar to what the OP wants. Perhaps you could describe the idea of attaching a context to a "drawable" in more detail or simply link to a place that does. Pointing out incorrect assumptions is good (if you can keep it less derogatory :)), providing answers and help is better. Down-voting the question certainly doesn't help in this case.